# Should over-writing variable names give any performance benefits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When parsing objects out of large datasets, I often find myself aggregating information into set objects, then transforming them into lists to sort them.

For example, here might be a code snippet:

```
all_times = set([])

for row in dataset:
   time = parse_out_time(row)
   all_times.add(time)

sorted_times = sorted(list(all_times))
```

My question is about that last assignment. I could reassign the same variable name with the sorted list

```
all_times = sorted(list(all_times))
```

I know that python has automatic garbage collection to remove the data assigned to old variable names that are not reused. This approach seems like it would allow the Python interpreter to immediately de-allocate the memory belonging to the old set version of all_times. If we ran the above code in a loop over a few million datasets, this could be important.

Should writing over variable names that you will never use again give any performance benefits? Or is Python's garbage collector smart enough to immediately de-allocate the memory for variables that are never called again by the script?

Comment: What do you mean *"never referenced again by name"*? They are still referred to by that name, whether you access them via it again or not, until the end of the scope in which the name was defined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added a clarification that the script never again calls that variable

Comment: Then no, as far as I'm aware there is no such optimisation. You should explicitly `del` identifiers you're no longer using (or assign them to something else, as you're currently doing) if there is a concern around holding onto large, unneeded objects - that also has the benefit of making your code work correctly in implementations that lack such an optimisation.

Comment: about assignment in Python, i found Brendan Rhodes's [talk](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#plummeting-cliff) about it very enlightening

Comment: ps, afaik you don't have to make a list out of it first to sort the set

Comment: Whatever happens with memory management and garbage collections is implementation detail of Python.  The answer to "does X give any performance benefit" is always try with it, try without, measure any difference.

Comment: @wim This question is about the implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't do any static analysis of the code. It will maintain the reference count for an object bound to a variable until that variable goes out of scope (for instance, on `return`), the variable is reassigned (`all_times = sorted(list(all_times)`) or is deleted (`del all_times`). In the case of a `set`, you could also do `all_times.clear()` to get rid of the contained data. All four are reasonable ways to get rid of a container that is no longer needed.

Notice in any case that the contained data is still in `sorted_times`. All you got rid of is the hash tables used by the set. Its likely not that big of a help either way.

Answer (score 1):

Il don't think it would cost so much resources if you do it right (depending on your needs).

I mean, If you run this code into a loop, you will still only use 2 variables.

Things will be slightly different if you put this code into a function, and run the function into a loop. And it would consume a little more if you run this function as multithreaded tasks.